# AMD FX 8350 potentially overheating

Tags: cpu, crash

I am worried that my CPU is overheating when running at maximum capacity.

I have not overclocked the machine. The machine often powers down after a couple of minutes of max CPU usage.

I get the following events in the Event Log after the crash:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          11/10/2013 12:05:40
Event ID:      41
Task Category: (63)
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      (2)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      home-pc
Description:
    The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
```

What can I do to confirm this or further narrow down this issue? Due to the sudden nature of the crash, no MEMORY.DMP is created I believe.

I am happy to post any extra information that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several temperature monitoring programs which you can use:

- [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) (my favorite)
- [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) (can write logs)
- And many more that I don't care to list

You can find some information regarding max temps for the FX-8350 [here](http://hardware.forumsee.com/a/m/s/p12-31883-0137783--official-8350-temps.html)

You can first try simply replacing the thermal paste because that is the cheapest option but if the temps still don't get to a comfortable level then you should replace the cooler especially if you are maxing out the CPU for lengthy periods of time.

Heat is the enemy of electronics because prolonged temps @ 55°-60° can cause hardware failure faster than if you can get it to run @ 40°-50°

Comment: The stock cooler is good enough to cool the CPU.  If the CPU is overheating then the stock thermal pad should be replaced.

Comment: @Ramhound Good point, I'll update the post to reflect that option as well

Comment: I'm checking these programs out now. So you are saying that even at max use, assuming the cooler is working as it should, the CPU should never overheat?

Comment: That is what Ramhound is suggesting but I have my doubts because you are dealing with an FX-8350. I personally feel that AMD is pushing their luck with a 4GHz chip on a stock cooler but stock thermal paste they put on the cooler is pretty bad. You have to consider the temperature of your room though because if your computer raises the temp of your room by one degree then the lowest possible temp of the chip raises by one degree. If your case can fit it then I would recommend a Cooler Master Hyper 212 Evo if you're not looking to break the bank.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have just added 3 extra case fans, two intakes and two outtakes. Running at max speed, the CPU is at 62-65. This is the first time the machine can run at max speed and not die. I'll check out changing the thermal paste though, it would be nice to see a lower temp, or even that cooler, thanks.